# Possible to run async function using exec?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am trying to call an async function from exec, I would expect it to work like:

```
def test():
    print("test")
    exec('def test2():\n    print("test")\ntest2()')
test()
```

Output:

```
test
test
```

So a function defined in exec is able to call itself, however we can't do such things in asyncio as:

```
async def test():
    print("test")
    exec('async def test2():\n    print("test")\nawait test2()')
```

We cant use await outside function as well as we cant call another loop from a running loop:

```
async def test():
    print("test")
    exec('async def test2():\n    print("test")\nasyncio.run(test2())')
```

Is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put current running loop as `exec()` global parameter:

```
import asyncio


async def test():
    print("test")
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    exec('async def test2():\n    print("test2")\nloop.create_task(test2())', {'loop': loop})

asyncio.run(test())
```

Prints:

```
test
test2
```

---

EDIT: To run asynchronously, you can return awaitable from the `exec()`:

```
import asyncio

async def some_other_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('some_other_task')

async def test():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    t = [None]

    exec('async def test2():\n    await asyncio.sleep(3);print("task in exec finished")\nt[0] = loop.create_task(test2())', {'asyncio': asyncio, 'loop': loop, 't': t})
    await asyncio.gather(some_other_task(), t[0])

asyncio.run(test())
```

Prints:

```
some_other_task           # <-- after 1 sec
task in exec finished     # <-- after 3 sec
```

Comment: `loop.create_task` behaves differently from `await`, though. Particularly, it doesn't *wait* for the task to finish.

Comment: That solved problem i asked. But how would i run both of these tasks asynchronously ?

Comment: Hi Andrej! You seem to be the pro here. I have encountered a similar problem that a function calls itself, a coroutine restarts a coroutine on the end, which is quite easy in golang. This simple code does not work as expected, even by replacing `create_task` to `ensure_future`, could you solve this problem? https://onecompiler.com/python/3xxn4busd

Comment: @GeorgeY It seems you're missing `await` keywords in `asyncio.sleep` and `asyncio.create_task` https://onecompiler.com/python/3xxncde7b

Comment: Interesting though, following your recommendation, the printing never ended.

Comment: @GeorgeY Maybe it would be better to create a question here on StackOverflow (and put there what have you tried so far and describe the problem). I can look at it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible. You would need some kind of "asynchronous `exec`" capable of suspending its own execution, and Python's syntax would need to support `await` outside an asynchronous function definition. Without that, there's no way for `exec` to return control to the event loop when it needs to suspend.

Andrej Kesely's answer **does not** work. It does not actually run the coroutine. It only arranges for the coroutine to run later.

Comment: @AndrejKesely: It's closer to correct, but the coroutine still doesn't run until some point after `exec` finishes. The execution order means that, for example, the code inside the `exec` can't use the output of any coroutines it wants to run.

Comment: "Not possible" might be a bit too strong. Couldn't an `async_exec` wrap the code into an `async def x():` (adding indentation), execute the definition of `x` in a namespace and then return `x()` (or return `await x()` if `async_exec` is itself async)? Some details will be different, e.g. the variables defined at top-level won't be really global, but it might not matter for the OP's use case.

Comment: Hi! Could you tell me how to correct this code into allowing recursive coroutines called from the end of itself? I kinda know why the recursion stops at step 2, but is there a way in python asyncio that allows this usage? https://onecompiler.com/python/3xxn4busd

Answer (score 0):

I needed something like this for a [project](https://asciinema.org/a/460467), and wrote an async version of [code.InteractiveConsole](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html).  I also wanted to capture output, so used an idea from [twisted.conch.Manhole](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/release-21.2.0-10091/src/twisted/conch/manhole.py)

This is an awful hack.  It only works for async code lines that start with "await".  I haven't worked out how to handle the form `x = await func()`.

```
import asyncio

def handle(output):
    print(f"** {output}", end="")

async def nested():
    return 42

async def main():
    localz = {"nested": nested}
    cons = AsyncConsole(handle, localz)
    await cons.interact("a = 10")
    await cons.interact("b = 20")
    await cons.interact("def fun(a, b):")
    await cons.interact("    return a + b")
    await cons.interact("")
    await cons.interact("fun(a, b)")
    await cons.interact("await nested()")

    del localz['__builtins__']
    print(f"l: {localz}")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
** >>> a = 10
** >>> b = 20
** >>> def fun(a, b):
** ...     return a + b
** ...
** >>> fun(a, b)
30
** >>> await nested()
42
l: {'nested': <function nested at 0x100ab0820>, 'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'fun': <function fun at 0x101059480>, '_': 42}
```

AsyncConsole:

```
import string
import code
import sys
import io


class AsyncConsole(code.InteractiveConsole):
    def __init__(self, handler, locals: dict = None, filename="<console>"):
        super().__init__(locals, filename)
        self.handler = handler
        self.filename = filename
        self.output = io.StringIO()
        self.prompt1 = ">>> "
        self.prompt2 = "... "
        self.prompt = self.prompt1
        self.is_async = False

    async def runcode(self, code):
        orighook, sys.displayhook = sys.displayhook, self.displayhook
        try:
            origout, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, self.output
            try:
                exec(code, self.locals)
                if self.is_async:
                    coro = self.locals["_"]
                    obj = await coro
                    self.locals["_"] = obj
                    if obj is not None:
                        self.write(repr(obj))
            except SystemExit:
                raise
            except Exception:
                self.showtraceback()
            finally:
                sys.stdout = origout
        finally:
            sys.displayhook = orighook

    def displayhook(self, obj):
        self.locals["_"] = obj
        if obj is not None and not self.is_async:
            self.write(repr(obj))

    def write(self, data):
        self.output.write(data)

    async def runsource(self, source, filename="<input>", symbol="single"):
        try:
            code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
        except (OverflowError, SyntaxError, ValueError):
            # Case 1
            self.showsyntaxerror(filename)
            return False

        if code is None:
            # Case 2
            return True

        # Case 3
        await self.runcode(code)
        return False

    async def push(self, line):
        self.buffer.append(line)
        source = "\n".join(self.buffer)
        more = await self.runsource(source, self.filename)
        if not more:
            self.resetbuffer()
        return more

    async def interact(self, line):
        self.is_async = line.startswith("await ")
        self.output = io.StringIO()
        self.output.write(f"{self.prompt}{line}\n")
        if self.is_async:
            line = line[6:]
        r = await self.push(line)
        self.prompt = self.prompt2 if r else self.prompt1
        if not r and "_" in self.locals and self.locals["_"]:
            self.output.write("\n")
        self.handler(self.output.getvalue())
        return self.prompt
```